# Historic market cap/outstanding shares

Tags: historical-data

Is there someway to get the historic market capitalization/outstanding shares of stocks traded in US exchanges ?

Comment: Do you have access to Bloomberg?

Comment: I don't have access to Bloomberg

Comment: You might want to check [quandl](http://www.quandl.com/stocks).

Comment: Quandl results are not reliable